# Queue message ends up on -poison queue

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-queues

I have a Logic App that monitors a Shared Mailbox and that writes a message to an Azure Queue if certain content is contained in the email.

The queue message triggers an Azure Function which does ‘stuff’.

However, in testing, my queue messages sometimes do, but often don’t trigger the function, and end up being moved to the poison queue, despite the content of the message always being the same.

I really don’t understand why sometimes my messages trigger the function and other times they get moved to the poison queue.

Can anyone explain?

Thanks.

Comment: Look inside the connected app insight instance... it will tell you what expectations are being thrown

Comment: the only reason they would be going to the poison queue is if indeed that are triggering the function and the function is throwing an error. post your function code

Comment: The message will be in posion queue because the message is not processed correctly, it should be the problem of your Function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71687686/messages-in-azure-message-queue-are-going-straight-to-the-poison-message-queue/   ??