# Messages in Azure Message Queue are going Straight to the Poison Message Queue

Tags: c#, azure, queue, message, poison

[Hoping this might save someone some time.]

The code below stopped working when moving to the newer [`QueueClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclient?view=azure-dotnet) class (in Azure.Storage.Queues) from the deprecated [`CloudQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueue?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) class (in Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue):

```
QueueClient queue = new QueueClient(accountConnectionString, "myQueuename");
queue.Create();
queue.SendMessage(msg);
```

Messages are being moved into the associated poison message queue, and I don't see any error messages in Azure's ApplicationInsights.

When I manually move the message in Azure Storage Explorer from the poison message queue back into the queue, it works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`CloudQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueue?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) class defaulted to using **`base64`** encoding in the prior v11 library, whereas [`QueueClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclient?view=azure-dotnet) does not!

To set **`base64`** encoding, add a [`QueueClientOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet):

```
QueueClientOptions queueOptions = new() { MessageEncoding = QueueMessageEncoding.Base64 };
QueueClient queue = new QueueClient(accountConnectionString, "myQueuename", queueOptions);
queue.Create();
queue.SendMessage(msg);
```